# Is it suspicious that a perfectly good question was removed by the author seconds after I posted a detailed answer?

Tags: discussion

I answered what seemed a perfectly valid and well thought out question in what I would consider to be a decent amount of detail. I then went back 10 seconds later to edit my answer to find that the question had been "voluntarily deleted by the user".

Being reasonably new to StackOverflow and without all that much experience of different user behaviour, I am at a loss as to why someone would do this? The question had been posted for several hours and had obviously had a lot of time put into its presentation. Why then wait until 10 seconds after I've posted what I consider to be a good answer to remove the question?

I suppose my question is - is this suspicious behaviour and something I should watch out for in the future?

Additionally, is there anyway to retrieve my answer? The original question url is [HttpClient wrapper with Autofac for Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787749/httpclient-wrapper-with-autofac-for-web-api)

Comment: I voted undelete.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily attribute this to malice. He probably found a solution right about the time you did.

Comment: It seems the Meta effect has worked for you. The question has already been undeleted.

Comment: Im equally as confused by it coming back as it going :) But glad to see it back anyway - thank you very much!

Comment: I've had questions deleted literally at *the moment of submitting* an answer -- "This question has been deleted 10 seconds ago", w00t!

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the user was able to read your detailed answer, comprehend it, test it, and quickly delete their question, all in the space of 10 seconds. It's also pretty senseless for them to do so. It's far more likely that during the several hours the poster had continued to work on the problem, found a solution (either elsewhere or on their own), and decided to remove the question since they didn't need the information any longer.

Comment: I would say it's coincidental. For the OP to delete your comment to spite you would have to require a personal, animosity-filled history between the two of you. What probably happened is that he either found the solution that directly addressed his problem, or he found a "detour" that avoids his initial problem altogether. Either way, I wouldn't take it personally.