# What to do when question gets deleted while writing an answer?

Tags: discussion

This question here: [What is the time complexity of findViewById() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281537/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-findviewbyid-method) has received three quick downvotes, a negative comment, and an answer which does not really address the question.

[image]

I actually think this is a rightful question, which is clear and concise. It is short, yes, but basically the asker wants to know how adding more `View`s and `ViewGroup`s to your layout affect the time cost of the `findViewById` method. I'm afraid the downvoters missed this clarity because of lack of knowledge about the term 'time complexity'.

I was in the middle of writing an answer, when I got a popup saying somewhat: 'This question is deleted and no answers will be accepted'. Apparently the asker didn't like the negativity and deleted the question. I have voted to undelete the question, but I'm doubting that'll do. I have also no way of contacting the OP without intruding on some other posts.

Am I right in my opinion, and what should I do?

Comment: Pretend it never happened, do nothing and move on.

Comment: Related: [Is it suspicious that a perfectly good question was removed by the author seconds after I posted a detailed answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265875/is-it-suspicious-that-a-perfectly-good-question-was-removed-by-the-author-second)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I agree that its a good question and something every Android dev should know.  No idea why he deleted it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do what *user2140173* said in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268605/what-to-do-when-question-gets-deleted-while-writing-an-answer#comment77443_268605).

Just go back to the main page and look for another question to answer.

There's nothing you can do. Yes it is annoying when you've spent some time putting an answer together and then you find you can't post it because the question is closed or deleted, but that's life.

Comment: Maybe that's life, but it's quite unkind behavior to those who may have just spent 10 minutes producing a detailed answer to what we decided was a question worth those 10 minutes.

Comment: @JosephLarson the problem is, at the moment, no one knows you're writing an answer so there's no way of informing the asker of this. There's probably a mechanism for detecting that you're typing in the answer box and sending that back to the server to then send out to the asker, but I suspect that it's just not worth the effort.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [what ChrisF answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268606) you could post your own self-answered question. Say you feel it's a really good question, it's not a duplicate, and your answer is valuable as well, then [by all means post it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

That said, as always with self-answered questions, make sure both the question and answer are good enough. Perhaps don't copy-paste the deleted question, but make it a good question of your own.

Comment: I'd add one more value-scenario: the user is new and answering their question will demonstrate the value of this platform. The question I had spent 15 minutes answering (only to be deleted seconds before I could hit submit) was, I believe, the result of uncertainty from the author regarding the question's value. It didn't have _enough_ value to SO to re-ask and re-answer the question myself. But it had enough value to 1) keep alive and 2) give the newbie author a morale boost that someone took the time to help him.