# OP removes question after being answered in comment

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, undeleted-questions

After tentatively answering a question, user removed the post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365052/angular-httpclient-prevent-array-indices-in-json-request). I meant to post as answer if I had correctly guessed the problem.

- This problem could be faced by others. The question was well described and included screenshots and proper information.
- I feel a bit uneasy, because I answer for the community too, I'm not OP's private consultant!
- User took the time to leave a message, but I cannot read it since the question cannot be accessed.

1) Should we undelete and suggest the OP to follow site rules and netiquette?

2) Also, how can I find that user? I cannot seem to be able to send him a message to tell him about this :D!.

3) Should users always be able to read posts (even deleted) if they have contributed to them in the past? (so I could at least read that comment). The "inbox" page doesn't show the entire comment either, nor the user name.

Comment: Undelete and view deleted posts is 499 reputation away from you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools ;)

Comment: Related, if not duplicate (as I expect the answer to be the same): [What to do when question gets deleted while writing an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268605/215552)

Comment: Also related: [Caveat emptor. Making students aware they cannot delete their homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440).

Comment: Leaving aside the main topic of your question here for a second and dealing with the linked question itself, I recommend you leave it deleted, don't try to undelete and answer it: it's just a **typo** question. You should not answer typo questions, what you did (clarifying the issue in a comment) is enough for the OP, which is right deleting their (again, typo) question. You may argue, as you did, that *"this problem could be faced by others"*, which in fact may be the case, but still we don't like typo Q/A pairs in S.O. So, leave it deleted.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ok, although I disagree it's a typo question in this case: the problem was a misunderstanding of how to interpret developer tools output.

Comment: Also related (just found it): [What can I do if a user removes a question after I've written an extended answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317470/what-can-i-do-if-a-user-removes-a-question-after-ive-written-an-extended-answer) and [I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question)

Comment: @jjmontes here at SO *"typo"* is an umbrella term, containing the situation described in the original question.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado still not a typo to me, this is not a "problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error", as other people could be missled by that browser's developer console formatting style.

Comment: The purpose of the “typo” close reason is for questions whose answer is highly localized and thus are unlikely to help anyone else in the future. If, as you say, the output is confusing and may be misinterpreted by others, then it’s a good question and should be kept. That’s a judgment call, though. Moderators do accept flags on deleted questions like this. Make sure to provide a compelling argument for your plea: why will the Q&A be useful to others? Alternatively, post an *even better* self-answered Q&A of your own to serve as a canonical.

Comment: Related: [What is a help vampire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Answer (score 22):

Based on OPs comment in response to yours:

> Yeah you're right, I made a mistake -> that's really just the
>   representation in the dev console. I got confused because when just
>   one object is in an array, the dev console doesnt display indices.
>   Thanks a lot for your help! It helped me locate my error which was
>   somewhere else.

It seems likely the question should have ended up closed as "no longer reproducible" anyway. Although it is frustrating when this happens (I've even had an accepted answer unaccepted and the question deleted afterwards), as is discussed in this [Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268605/what-to-do-when-question-gets-deleted-while-writing-an-answer) it really is best to just move on. There are many more questions to answer...

Comment: The key question is re: `I got confused because when just one object is in an array, the dev console doesnt display indices.` If this is deemed a common "beginner's problem" or confusion, there's argument that it's not a typo, but an XY problem (what and what isn't represented in the dev console).

Comment: @jpp I wasn't suggesting it was a typo; I think it's no longer reproducible because OP realised that they made a mistake interpreting what is in fact valid output, and that their actual problem was somewhere else i.e. not in the question at all.

Comment: But it *is* reproducible.. by a new user coming along and making the same mistake! SO is all about educating and correcting misunderstandings. This may seem a "trivial" misunderstanding, but it's still one that *can* conceivably occur to several people.